# Horizontally scroll single line UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I need a view that allows me to have an editable method of text entry that is limited to one line, but can scroll horizontally. After a bit of research, I found that maybe a UITextView would work well.

This is going in a table view cell so I've tried putting this in `awakeFromNib()`

```
code.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 1
code.layoutManager.textContainerChangedGeometry(code.textContainer)
```

but this is what happens (I'm repeating the same line to fill the text view)

[image]

So for attributes I need to assign, I need:

- Disable Vertical scrolling
- Enable Horizontal scrolling
- Limit Text View to one line

If anyone also knows a better way to do this (maybe with a scrollable Text Field?) I would love to hear it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "a view that allows me to have an editable method of text entry that is limited to one line, but can scroll horizontally" Isn't that what a UITextField is?

Comment: @matt Ok so I implemented one in place of the text view. I like the operation but is there a way I can scroll horizontally by swiping across it without having to click into editing it?

Comment: That behavior is not built-in. The scrolling follows the selection. You can use UITextInput features of UITextField to set the selection.